# Sending unicode characters to mysql database with Python

Tags: python, unicode, mysql-python

I 've been having a lot of trouble with sending unicode characters to a database for the last couple of hours. I am using the MySQLdb Python library. I had to first declare the enconding, so that I could save the file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Than I added charset="utf8",use_unicode=True as parametres in the connect function.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="146.247.111.111",user="xxxxxxxx",passwd="[redacted]",db="xxxxxxxx",charset="utf8",use_unicode=True)
db.set_character_set('utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xls_pravne_osebe_users(name,email,Wall_idWall) VALUES(%s,%s,1) ",("šđčđĐĐšš","ŽŽŽŽŽŽ"))
```

It definitely changed something, yet everything is still not the way it should be. The letters ž and š are alright, which they weren't before I added the encoding parameters, however the letters ćčđ are still not alright. All of these characters are unicode characters. What encoding is this, that properly encodes some characters and fails with others of the same family?

Comment: I masked your password; as you have posted the actual IP of the machine.

Comment: What is your database table collation?

Comment: utf8 is the collation

Comment: What version of Python is this?

Comment: It is Python 2.7. I have just found the problem. The table collation is utf8, but the collation is latin1_swedish_ci. I don't know why it is like that, but this was the problem.